# windows phone 8 async web request with mvvm

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8, httpwebrequest

I use mvvm design pattern in my app. On a button's click from the view, it lunch a method in my view model, and from the viewmodel another method in model to get content from a web address by a web request. Since the web request is a async method, I implemented a Observer design pattern to push the request's response from the data service to my view model.

2 questions :

1. Is it a good idea ?
2. How can I push the response from my viewmodel to the view ? A second Observer dp ?

Thanks.

**EDIT** : 
I change my code to use INotifyPropertyChanged, but I still block on the update of the view...

in my view :

```
private void searchButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    vm = new ResultSearchViewModel();
    vm.Search(stringRequest);

    DataContext = vm.ResponseParse;
}
```

in my view model :

```
class ResultSearchViewModel
{
    private string _response
    {
        get { return App.WR.Result; }
    }

    public ContainerResult ResponseParse
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_response != null)
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContainerResult>(_response);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Search(string searchContent)
    {
        App.WR.Get("http://api.deezer.com/search?q=" + searchContent);
    }
}
```

App.WR is a service I have in my application :

```
public class WebRequestService : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string result;
    public string Result
    {
        get { return result; }
        set
        {
            result = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Result");
        }
    }

    public string Uri;
    public HttpWebRequest Request;


    public void Get(string _uri)
    {
        Uri = _uri;

        Request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Uri);
        Request.BeginGetResponse(GetStringFromStream, Request);
    }

    private void GetStringFromStream(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
        if (request != null)
        {
            try
            {
                WebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(result);

                try
                {
                    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), true);
                    try
                    {
                        Result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        streamReader.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (WebException e)
                {
                    Result = e.ToString();
                }
                finally
                {
                    response.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                Result = e.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

The web request work and I can see the Json correctly Parse if I add som Debug.WriteLine but I really don't know how to update the view...
I'll really appreciate if somebody know how to do that :)

Comment: Your View Model should not have a method (ideally). A model just stores and transaports data. Use `async` `await` and get your data in a `Task`. The `Task` will return when it has your data.

Comment: @SamLeach I tried your solution that seems really good but I have an error on "request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);" the error says "cannot await IAsyncResult"

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd typically expect to see this done would be:

- Button on view is bound to a Command in the ViewModel.
- Command executes method on an injected service, or directly in the Model, which requests the data.
- Response is used to populate a property (or properties) of the VM.
- The property is bound to the View so that changes are displayed there.